# call function on iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, constants, const-correctness

I have a std::list of "Ray"-objects, which I want to iterate over.

```
for (std::list<Ray>::const_iterator it = clRay.begin(), end = clRay.end(); it != end; ++it) {
    *it->setDir( m_v3Position - *it->getOrigin() )
}
```

And the Ray objects have the methods setDir() and getOrigin():

```
const QVector3D &getOrigin() const {
    return m_v3Origin;
}

void setDir( const QVector3D   &dir )
{
    m_v3Dir = dir;
}
```

The setdir() is no problem for the compiler, but I can't call getOrigin(). Because then I get the error:

```
src/AreaLight.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void AreaLight::shadowFeeler(std::__cxx11::list<Ray>&, double&, ColorType&) const’:
src/AreaLight.cpp:18:17: error: no match for ‘operator*’ (operand type is ‘const QVector3D’)
```

I think it is a const-problem, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: `*it->setDir( m_v3Position - *it->getOrigin() ) `    ->    `it->setDir( m_v3Position - it->getOrigin() )`

Comment: Or for range: `for (auto& r : clRay) { r.setDir( m_v3Position - r.getOrigin() ); }`

Comment: if I use `it->setDir( m_v3Position - it->getOrigin() )`  I get the error `src/AreaLight.cpp:18:47: error: passing ‘const Ray’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
`

Comment: but the solution of @Jarod42 seems to work pretty well.

Comment: If you keep to use `iterator`, you should not use `const_iterator`

Comment: When you code, you should understand what you do and not try random things. Obviously, you were using `const_iterator` and were calling `setDir` which is not a constant function which does not make much sense.

Comment: @Phil1970 you are right and yes, afterwards it was obviously not smart what I've done, but I think everyone of us know the moment when one doesn't see his own mistakes in his code, even if they are obvious or not.

Comment: @Jarod42 thank you, this also fixed my problem

Comment: @Phil1970 But in this case, you are right, the main problem was my lack of knowledge with const correctness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You wrote `*it->`. You should write just `it->`. There's only one level of indirection here.

This affects both calls.

In fact, the call to `setDir` is broken for another reason, which is that it is non-`const` and you are trying to get to it through a `const_iterator`. Adding a `*` doesn't fix that problem; it just masks it with a new problem. Randomly adding yet more `*`s, without understanding what they mean, isn't the way to go either.